# Swift : How to set Custom UICollectionViewCell as circle?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've custom `UICollectionViewCell` that contains `UILabel` and `UIImage`.
I want to set the cell in circular format.

**Note:-** `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` cannot be changed due to AutoLayout.

Below is code that I've used :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath ) -> CGSize {

          return CGSize(width: (self.objKeypadCollectionView.frame.size.width/3)-10, height: (self.objKeypadCollectionView.frame.size.height/4)-10)
    }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let objKeypadCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("idKeypadCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! KeypadCollectionViewCell

        if (self.numberArray[indexPath.item])=="asda" {
            objKeypadCollectionViewCell.lblNumber.text = ""
            objKeypadCollectionViewCell.imgPrint.hidden = false
        }
        else if (self.numberArray[indexPath.item])=="Derterel" {
            objKeypadCollectionViewCell.lblNumber.text = self.numberArray[indexPath.item]
            objKeypadCollectionViewCell.imgPrint.hidden = true
        }
        else {
            objKeypadCollectionViewCell.imgPrint.hidden = true
            objKeypadCollectionViewCell.lblNumber.text = self.numberArray[indexPath.item]
            objKeypadCollectionViewCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
            objKeypadCollectionViewCell.layer.borderWidth = 1
            objKeypadCollectionViewCell.layer.cornerRadius = objKeypadCollectionViewCell.frame.size.width/2
        }
        return objKeypadCollectionViewCell
    }
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Design screen]

Comment: its the image or button or the collectionview cell

Comment: Well, if you really cannot change your `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` implementation, then the easiest way to achieve what you want would be to add a dummy rectangular view to your cells and set your border and corner radius on it.

Comment: Why don't you simply change the keyboard type to do this?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : It is label whose cornerRadius is set to make it circular

Comment: @Desdenova : Didn't get you

Comment: @JayprakashDubey - chek the updated answer bro

Comment: There is a special keyboard type just for this purpose. [UITextInputTraits](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIKeyboardType)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is my UICollectionView Example which you can check for your solution. I am using storyboard to setup the primary collectionView with AutoLayout. Also, attaching some screenshots to clarify the result.

There is a method called `drawRect()`. You can use that inside your collectionView Cell class for doing the UI stuffs.

Now here is my code.

**1. ViewController.swift**  //Just the normal `UIViewController` like yours, nothing else... :)

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  CollectionCheckCircle
//
//  Created by Tuhin Samui on 02/09/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Tuhin Samui. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 200
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cellOfCollection = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellCollectionView", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        return cellOfCollection
    }

}
```

**2. CollectionViewCell.swift** //Just a `UICollectionViewCell` class for dequeuing the cell.

```
//
//  CollectionViewCell.swift
//  CollectionCheckCircle
//
//  Created by Tuhin Samui on 02/09/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Tuhin Samui. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) { //Your code should go here.
        super.drawRect(rect)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2
    }

}
```

Note: I am not using either any `flowlayout` of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` or cell size inside `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` for this collectionView. You can add those things too. Please do some experiments as per your needs. BTW I am using Xcode 7.3.1 and Swift 2.2.

Here is the storyboard screenshot for collectionView setup and result on the simulator.
[image: First Storyboard screenshot with simulator result]

[image: Second Storyboard screenshot with simulator result]

Hope this helped. Sorry for any mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Just try to give corner radius as height/2, make sure cell should have same height and width.

```
cell.layer.cornerRadius = min(cell.frame.size.height, cell.frame.size.width) / 2.0

cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Please, let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Height and Width are generated programmatically. It varies depending on device size

Comment: then min fun will be taking care. Please, check and let me know.

Comment: This is not working. It shows elliptical shape instead of circle.

Comment: then your view must be in square. Now you can add another view on cell and make that as circle with same solution.

Comment: drawRect method is the key here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is cell's `width` and `height` is changed at run time according to your screen width, So to solve this issue add one square `UIView` inside your cell and use that `UIView` inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method to make it circle view like this.

```
objKeypadCollectionViewCell.circleView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
objKeypadCollectionViewCell.circleView.layer.borderWidth = 1
objKeypadCollectionViewCell.circleView.layer.cornerRadius = objKeypadCollectionViewCell.frame.size.width/2
objKeypadCollectionViewCell.circleView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this updated cell.

```
class KeypadCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var circularBGLayer: CALayer!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        circularBGLayer = CALayer()
        circularBGLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        layer.addSublayer(circularBGLayer)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        var frame = self.bounds
        frame.size.width = min(frame.width, frame.height)
        frame.size.height = frame.width
        circularBGLayer.bounds = frame
        circularBGLayer.cornerRadius = frame.width*0.5
        circularBGLayer.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By giving this line for calculating the height of your cell

```
return CGSize(width: (self.objKeypadCollectionView.frame.size.width/3)-10, height: (self.objKeypadCollectionView.frame.size.height/4)-10)
```

You cant achieve what you want. Use Aspect Ratio technique. For Height and width of cell use your screen width and based on that aspect ratio update your cell height and width then and only then this line works....

If you need clarification skype me iammubin38

Answer (score 0):

You can try UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout ....

Add delegate first.

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
            let collectionWidth = CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.bounds);
                var itemWidth = collectionWidth / 3 - 1;
                return CGSizeMake(itemWidth, itemWidth);
            }
        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 1
        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 1
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey check this code.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath ) -> CGSize {
CGSize size = CGSize(width: (self.objKeypadCollectionView.frame.size.width/3)-10, height: (self.objKeypadCollectionView.frame.size.height/4)-10);
CGFloat width = size.width;
CGFloat height = size.height;
  if (width < height) {
     height = width;
   } else {
     width = height;
   }
   return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift 5

```swift
import UIKit
import Kingfisher

class StoryCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    
// this override can make the circle

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2
    }

}
```